# Pods are not communicating with each other after patching podcidr

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to add new node to my K8s cluster, after adding it in cluster i started getting following error in canal pod-

`Error registering network: failed to acquire lease: node "e2e-98-15.ssdcloudindia.net" pod cidr not assigned`

To fix this i ran following command -

`kubectl patch node e2e-98-15.ssdcloudindia.net -p '{"spec":{"podCIDR":"10.244.15.0/16"}}'`

But after running this command none of the pods are communicating with each other. I am getting errors like "not able to find given endpoints", and i am not able to ping or curl.

Please help me with this.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried any troubleshooting steps?

Answer (score 0):

I got solution. It was network conflict i resolved it.
https://blogs.iamabhishek.me/2022/09/solved-pod-cidr-not-assigned.html